# Error al realizar un loop con test estadísticos

Tags: r

Estoy intentando ejecutar un loop para ejecutar múltiples veces un test de shapiro.
Para ello me he basado del siguiente link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58253937/loop-for-shapiro-wilk-normality-test-for-multiple-variables-in-r).

Siguiendo los pasos, realizo el subset de mi variable de interés:

Partiendo de mi database (checking 3835x9 variables):

```
Estadia  Edad TALLA_D PESO_D   IMC `Linfocitos totales` `Albumina total` `Colesterol total` Conut_stage
18    80      NA   67.5    NA                 0.89              3.3                123 Light (2-4)
 6    87      NA   NA      NA                 6.4               3.9                120 Light (2-4)
 2    66      NA   NA      NA                 1.37              4.1                153 Low (0-1)  
14    63      NA   NA      NA                 1.04              3.8                239 Low (0-1)  
 2    58     180  129      40                 2.44             NA                   NA NA         
 3    82      NA   NA      NA                 1.18              4.2                130 Light (2-4)
 5    18      NA   NA      NA                 0.9               4.1                130 Light (2-4)
 9    34     151   80      35                 0.7               4                  220 Light (2-4)
 5    76      NA   NA      NA                 1.02             NA                   NA NA         
44    75      NA   NA      NA                 1.42              3.6                165 Low (0-1)  



     My_list <- split(checking, f = list(checking$Conut_stage))
```

Preparo la lista:
loop_Shapiro_1 <- list()

Y realizo el loop:

```
     for (name in names(My_list)){
       My_sub <- My_list[[name]]
       loop_Shapiro_1[[name]] <- lillie.test(My_sub$Edad)
     }
```

El problema es que me gustaría realizaro para todas las columnas que tengo en el dataframe (que son 9), en vez de ir realizando el loop por cada variable Edad, IMC, Estadia, etc.

Para ello he intentado cambiar el código del loop sin especificar la columna respecto a la que quiero realizar el loop:

```
     for (name in names(My_list)){
       My_sub <- My_list[[name]]
       loop_Shapiro_1[[name]] <- lillie.test(My_sub)
     }
```

Sin embargo obtengo el siguiente error:

```
          Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
          i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
          x Input has size 9 but subscript `complete.cases(x)` has size 960.
          Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

¿Qué deberia cambiar para que se hiciera el loop con todas las variables del dataframe?

Por otro lado estoy intentando realizar el mismo loop con el test de levene, el cual ni me funciona:

Recojo el nombre de las variables que quiero realizar el test de levene

```
    name_col<-colnames(checking[1:8])
```

Creo la lista para recoger el output:
loop_levene <- list()

Ejecuto el loop:

```
  for (val in name_col) {
     loop_levene<-leveneTest(val ~ Conut_stage, BD)
    }
```

Y obtengo el siguiente error:

```
     Error in model.frame.default(form, data) : 
       variable lengths differ (found for 'Conut_stage')
```

¿Qué estoy realizando mal?
Gracias de antemano

EDIT1:
siguiendo las sugerencias en los comentarios de este post he cambiado ambos códigos:

```
    loop_Shapiro <- list()
    variables <- colnames(My_list[[1]])[unlist(lapply(My_list[[1]], is.numeric))]
    for (name in names(My_list)){
      My_sub <- My_list[[name]]
      for (v in variables) {  
        nombre <- paste0(name, '_', v)
        loop_Shapiro[[nombre]] <- lillie.test(My_sub[,v])
      }
    }
```

Obteniendo el siguiente error:

```
    Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
    i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
    x Input has size 1 but subscript `complete.cases(x)` has size 960.
    Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Para el segundo test también he cambiado el código (siguiendo los comentarios del post):

```
    name_col<-colnames(checking[1:8])
    loop_levene <- list()

    for (val in name_col) {
      f <- formula(paste(val, '~ Conut_stage'))
      loop_levene <- leveneTest(f, BD)
    }
```

El cual obtengo el resultado deseado pero para la última variable a medir, es decir Colesterol total. Entiendo que se está sobreescribiendo por encima ¿Cómo puedo solucioanr este problema?
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según se lee en la [documentación](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nortest/versions/1.0-4/topics/lillie.test), el test de Kolmogorov-Smirnov espera:

> a numeric vector of data values, the number of which must be greater
> than 4. Missing values are allowed.

Por consiguiente, no se puede pasar un data.frame con la idea de que vaya a hacer el test sobre todas las variables, necesitas iterar además de por cada grupo, por cada variable o columna y extraer estas como un vector no como la columna de un `data.frame`:

```
loop_Shapiro <- list()
variables <- colnames(My_list[[1]])[unlist(lapply(My_list[[1]], is.numeric))]
for (name in names(My_list)){
  My_sub <- My_list[[name]]
  for (v in variables) {  
    nombre <- paste0(name, '_', v)
    loop_Shapiro[[nombre]] <- lillie.test(My_sub[,v])
  }
}
```

En primer lugar obtenemos los nombres de aquellas columnas que sean numéricas, luego dentro del ciclo de los grupos incorporamos otro para iterar sobre cada variable y aplicamos el test, el elemento en la lista se llamará con el nombre del grupo y la variable.

Con respecto al test de [Levene](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/3.0-11/topics/leveneTest) se espera:

> response variable for the default method, or a lm or formula object.
> If y is a linear-model object or a formula, the variables on the
> right-hand-side of the model must all be factors and must be
> completely crossed.

En tu caso estás intentando pasar una formula:

```
loop_levene <- leveneTest(val ~ Conut_stage, BD)
```

Sin embargo, aquí el problema es que `val` no representa la columna o variable del `data.frame` sino que es una cadena con el nombre de la misma. Lo que debería hacer es, a partir de la cadena con el nombre de la variable, crear la formula dinámicamente:

```
f <- formula(paste0('`', val, '`', ' ~ Conut_stage'))
loop_levene[[val]] <- leveneTest(f, BD)
```

Recuerda también que hay que para inserta un nuevo elemento debes indicar un índice, por ejemplo el nombre de la variable.

Otro problema que estarías teniendo es  con la variable `Conut_stage`, hay observaciones en esta variable que están en blanco, lo que estaría provocando un problema finalmente aquí:

```
My_list[[name]] # que es básicamente My_list[[""]] 
NULL
```

esto hace que el test sea `lillie.test(NULL)` y tengas el error que mencionas. La solución es renombrar los grupos en blanco, para que el `split` deje una lista indexada con un nombre adecuado para todos los grupoas:

```
checking[, "Conut_stage"] <- ifelse(checking[, "Conut_stage"] == "", "No disponible", checking[, "Conut_stage"])
My_list <- split(checking, f = list(checking$Conut_stage))
```

Comment: Hola Patricio, muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta. He intentado ejecutar ambos códigos y no obtengo el resultado obtenido. La primera parte la ejecuto como me has indicado y obtengo el siguiente error: Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
x Input has size 1 but subscript `complete.cases(x)` has size 960.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Por otro lado al ejecutar el loop para el test de levene name_col<-colnames(checking[1:8]
loop_levene <- list()

for (val in name_col) {
  f <- formula(paste(val, '~ Conut_stage'))
  loop_levene <- leveneTest(f, BD)
}
obtengo el siguiente error:  Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:12: unexpected symbol
1: Linfocitos totales
               ^
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In leveneTest.default(y = y, group = group, ...) :
  group coerced to factor.
2: In leveneTest.default(y = y, group = group, ...) :
  group coerced to factor.
(y así 5 veces) ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Adrián, el primer problema no le encuentro sentido, podrías decirme en que instrucción precisa te estaría dando? El otro problema, me parece que tiene que ver con los nombres de las columnas, veo que tienen espacios lo que suele complicar las cosas, prueba agregar los backticks para el nombre de la variable, ahora edito mi respuesta para que lo veas, no puedo indicarlo en un comentario por que no se interpreta bien.

Comment: Respecto al primer tema; el error me lo da al ejecutar el loop for. El segundo tema he cambiado los espacios por "_" y me funciona pero con el último valor de name_col en vez de todos los valores. Esto lo se porque imprimo el valor de f y me sale el último valor de la tabla, quizás se está sobreescribiendo

Comment: Respecto al primer tema: He estado revisando el archivo generado de My_sub y genera el mismo archivo que My_list con la variable adicional de Conut_stage (la cual se utilizó previamente para crear una lista de los datos: My_list <- split(checking, f = list(checking$Conut_stage)). Esto quiere decir que My_list también tiene dicha variable así que me he puesto a eliminarla: My_list$`Light (2-4)`[9]<-NULL My_list$`Low (0-1)`[9]<-NULL My_list$`Moderate (5-8)`[9]<-NULL My_list$`Severe (9-12)`[,9]<-NULL y aunque ya elimino la variable que se habia utilizado para dividir ,me da el mismo error.