# Error: Loop con test de normalidad y de homocedasticidad

Tags: r

Escribo de nuevo la pregunta ya que en [la anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/476535/error-al-realizar-un-loop-con-test-estad%c3%adsticos/476552?noredirect=1#comment848379_476552) no expuse la duda correctamente y ya se resolvió la pregunta. No obstante el código me sigue sin funcionar, es por ello por lo que voy a plantear la duda desde el principio:

Tengo un dataframe de 3825 por 9 columnas; este está depositado en [este link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1moTfY9LnCMoKqrW6nm3Mg8H6TB0m5XrA/view?usp=sharing). Me gustaría saber la normalidad y la homocedasticidad de cada una de las variables en función de la variable `Conut_stage`.

Para ello he ejecutado los siguientes códigos, que no funcionan correctamente:

Hago una lista de cada variable en función de `Conut_stage`

```
   My_list <- split(checking, f = list(checking$Conut_stage))
```

Realizo el loop:

```
loop_Shapiro <- list()
    variables <- colnames(My_list[[1]])[unlist(lapply(My_list[[1]], is.numeric))]
    for (name in names(My_list)){
      My_sub <- My_list[[name]]
      for (v in variables) {  
        nombre <- paste0(name, '_', v)
        loop_Shapiro[[nombre]] <- lillie.test(My_sub[,v])
      }
    }
```

Obteniendo el siguiente error:

```
       Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
       i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
       x Input has size 1 but subscript `complete.cases(x)` has size 960.
       Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Para el segundo test realizo el siguiente código:

Selecciono las variables a las que quiero realizar el test de levene:

```
     name_col<-colnames(checking[1:8])


     loop_levene <- list()
     for (val in name_col) {
       f <- formula(paste0('`', val, '`', ' ~ Conut_stage'))
       loop_levene <- leveneTest(f, checking)
     }
```

Y este código funciona bien pero me almacena solamente el resultado de la última variable, es decir `LBXTCA`. Me gustaría saber cómo hacer para que no se sobreescriban los resultados.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Adrián, el segundo error es simple, para agregar a la lista deberías hacer algo así: ` loop_levene[[val]] <- leveneTest(f, checking)`. Por el primer error, intente probar con el extracto de los datos que has publicado, pero hay muy poca información, pero de todas formas, probando solo las dos variables que no tienen NA, el código funciona adecuadamente.  Sin probar con los datos completos, lamentablemente no puedo decirte mucho más.

Comment: Patricio, respecto a la solución del segundo error funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias. En referencia al primer error, voy a actualizar la tabla total a ver si con ello se puede hacer. No obstante el test no toma en cuenta los valores con NA por lo que se podrían eliminar previamente

Comment: @PatricioMoracho quizás se pueda incluir en el loop que cuando se trabaje con la variable x para testear previamente elimine los valores de NA ¿no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema pareciera estar `Conut_stage`, hay observaciones en esta variable en blanco, lo que estaría provocando el problema finalmente aquí:

```
My_list[[name]] # que es básicamente My_list[[""]] 
NULL
```

esto hace que el test sea `lillie.test(NULL)` y tengas el error que mencionas. La solución es renombrar los grupos en blanco, para que el `split` deje una lista indexada con un nombre adecuado para todos los grupoas:

```
checking[, "Conut_stage"] <- ifelse(checking[, "Conut_stage"] == "", "No disponible", checking[, "Conut_stage"])
My_list <- split(checking, f = list(checking$Conut_stage))
```

Comment: Funciona!!! voy a reescribir la pregunta para que este hilo pueda servir a más gente que necesite realizar un loop de estos test. Muchas gracias Patricio

Comment: Si quieres @Patricio pon la solución en el link adicional y así también te llevas la recompensa que puse en un pasado